# HTML layout with flexible div

Tags: html, css, layout

Is it possible to create a markup as below?

```
Sample 1..................Right 1
Text2.....................Right Text 2
Another Text3.............Right 3
```

So far I have:

HTML :

```
<div class="left-most-div">Sample 1</div>
<div class="center-div">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="right-most-div">Right 1</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="left-most-div">Text2</div>
<div class="center-div">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="right-most-div">Right Text2</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="left-most-div">Another Text 3</div>
<div class="center-div">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="right-most-div">Right 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center_div { 
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa; 
}
.clear { 
  clear:both; 
}
```

center div is of flexible length adjusts based on the size of the left most div. 
Right most div has its left edge fixed.

Comment: What are you going to be displaying? From your description it sounds like it might be tabular data, in which case the usually dreaded <table> would be the right option.

Comment: I don't think it can be possible just with css and html maybe including Jquery

Comment: Like this with Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/kzrXX/15/

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin - a table would be justifiable but the poor misunderstood `<dl>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Anthony - Didn't even know that existed. Every day a schoolday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## adjustable center div to left div's content

what are you asking is a **left** div variable, a **center** div adjustable for the remain space, and a **right** div fixed, here is what I propose:

## the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vYhV/1/)

```
<div class="left-col">
  <div class="left-text">this is your text</div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
</div>
<div class="right-col">this is right fixed</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>

<div class="left-col">
  <div class="left-text">this is </div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
</div>
<div class="right-col">this </div>
<div class="clearer"></div>

<div class="left-col">
  <div class="left-text"> is your text</div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
</div>
<div class="right-col">this is right fixed</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.left-col{
  width:200px;
}
.left-col,
.right-col{
  float:left;
}
.left-text,
.dotted{
    display:table-cell;
}
.left-text{
    width: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dotted{
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
}
.clearer{
    clear:both;
}
```

**EDIT**: cleaner html:

## the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vYhV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this:

```
<div class="float-left">Left</div>
<div class="float-center">Center</div>
<div class="float-right">Right</div>
```

For the CSS

```
.float-right {
  text-align: left; // here is the trick :)
}
```

Now, when the text for the div that has to be placed at the very right side will be rendered, it will be placed in a Left-To-Right order! This way, you can manage the content.

However you might need to add this too

```
.float-center, .float-left, .float-right {
   display: inline-block; // to show them inline..
}
```

Now you will see the text as you want it to be.

Here is a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/cf3gD/1/ try to add some few more words to it! :) You'll see the `Right` managing itself.

Comment: I need multiple lines in the format displayed, not just one line. And have dots in the middle. Just like the jQuery fiddle by Danko.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/S2A9c/1/

Can be done with display table-cell

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="float-left td">Left</div>
    <div class="float-center td">Center</div>
    <div class="float-right td">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
}
.float-left {
    width: 100px;
    background: green;
}
.float-right {
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
```

I put some width for the first and last divs, I am not sure what's the requirement on those 2 cells are. This works without defined width but you might not get the exact width for the left/right divs

Comment: I guess the OP wants those divs first and last, with dynamic width

Comment: well then the OP can set the first/last to 1% width, http://jsfiddle.net/S2A9c/2/ only tested on FF/chrome/ie9(VM)